# 2012 vw jetta rear brake shoes

Tags: brakes, vw, jetta

I replaced rear shoes and drums on my 2012 jetta got the shoes on but new drums will not go on is there any kind of adjustment to get the drums to go on freely

Comment: [Does this video help](https://youtu.be/RDdZskGuNq4)? That is supposed to be for a 2005-2010 (I think), but it could apply to your situation.

Comment: I hate VW rear drum brakes. Make sure the adjustment lever is all the way in so you can slide the drum on then adjust out from there, It's a huge PITA and if the rear adjustment isn't done right the brake pedal will feel soft.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to compress your pistons in the wheel cylinder to make room**

If you compress your piston back into the clylinder (labeled below as the wheel cylinder) it will make room for the new brake shoes.  When you get new brake shoes they have more material on them than the old shoes which have been worn out and are thinner than when new.

You will then also use the adjuster wedge to decrease the OD (outside diameter) of the shoes so they will fit back into the drum.

This is a normal part of the brake job and nothing is wrong with the vehicle.

[image]

*Image from photobucket